# works with .java but not as .jar

Tags: java

So I'm making a JForm program in Netbeans, it works fine when I run the individual .java files or when I run the project as a whole but as soon as I try and "pack" the program into a .jar file it just falls over. I'm 90% sure the code is fine. I've done a bit of research before posting and I think I may need to try and put the java libraries with the program? Anyway here's the error code I'm getting.

[image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqxL2.png)

*Edit*

I've re-created the program and it's still not working on another project, this is the code:

```
package workproject;

import java.awt.Toolkit;


/**
 *
 * @author Robert
 */
public class WorkProject extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form WorkProject
     */
    public WorkProject() {
        initComponents();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("assets\\icon.png")));
    }
```

if I were to comment out the set icon line it would work fine, it also works fine when I run it in the net beans IDE but if, as stated earlier I create a .jar it won't run.

Comment: How can you run `.java` files?

Comment: Yes, the java files work no problem.

Comment: What's the structure of your project? It looks like a file is missing but I can't tell without knowledge of the project structure.

Comment: You didn't include other resources such as images. These missing images are resolved to `null`. Hence the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: You didn't provide any code or error message, but I'm going to make a wild guess that you're using `getFile()` on a resource instead of `getResourceAsStream()`.

Comment: @Makoto I think this is actually a duplicate of "using `File` in a jar".

Comment: Questions need to stand on their own. Include the error(s) as text. Include the code that's causing the error.

Comment: Thanks for the help thus far, please see the edit for the code!

Comment: The file must be case sensitively present in the jar. Do `"/assets/icon.png"` and check that it is in the jar (zip format).

Comment: The image is in the jar so i don't know what is going on there!
https://i.imgur.com/6ZJftTn.png